# #define related Query

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was doing code porting from Linux to Windows. I am using Visual Studio environment. I am stuck with one problem.

There is a function call with 2 parameters for Acquire and Release a semaphore in Windows.
The Linux code has one parameter
Windows:

```
KeInitializeSpinLock(spinlock,oldIRQL);
```

Linux

```
spin_lock_init(spinlock);
```

I have generic call like which I have to use :

```
Get_Lock(spinlock);
```

How do I do this for windows without changing the prototype of `Get_Lock` ?

I tried the following :

```
#define Get_Lock(lock) \

KIRQL  oldIrql;\

KeAcquireSpinLock(&(lock),&oldIrql);

#define Release_Lock(sync) KeReleaseSpinLock(&(sync),oldIrql)
```

But the compiler is giving errors .. Basically I want to retain the value of `oldIrql` because that value is needed for `KeReleaseSpinLock`

Error

```
error C2275: 'KIRQL' : illegal use of this type as an expression
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'oldIrql'
error C2065: 'oldIrql' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'oldIrql' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'oldIrql' : undeclared identifier
```

`KIRQL` is defined as

```
typedef UCHAR KIRQL
```

What wrong am I doing here ? Or Is there any other method which is there which can be used without changing the prototype of the `Get_Lock` and `Release_Lock`?

Comment: What error is the compiler giving you with your version?

Comment: Presumably the error is that `oldIrql` is undefined when `Release_Lock` is invoked? As `Get_Lock()`, where `oldIrql` is declared, is not necessarily invoked in the same scope where `Release_Lock()` is invoked.

Comment: In the `#define` you posted in your question, are there really all those empty lines?

Comment: From the error message it is clear that the compiler doesn't like the line `KIRQL oldIrql`, since that is the only time`KIRQL` appears. Now you get to put on your thinking cap. Why is the compiler expecting an expression here? Hint: The ability to declare variables other than the start of a block is not supported by all C compilers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to Microsoft compiler's only supporting C89 standard, which does not allow the intermingling of code and declarations. `Get_Lock()` is being called after a line of code (I suspect), which introduces the declaration of `oldIrql`.

If it is the case that the lock is obtained and released in the same scope always a possible fix (hack) would be to declare `KIRQL oldIrql;` at the top of the scope where `Get_Lock()` and `Release_Lock()` is called, and remove the declaration from `Get_Lock()`.

A tidier solution would be to eliminate the macros and introduce a new `struct` that defines a lock. For example:

```
typedef struct _lock
{
#ifdef WIN32
    UCHAR       oldIrql;
    PKSPIN_LOCK sem;
#else
#endif
} lock;

lock* lock_new()
{
    lock* result = malloc(sizeof(lock));

    /* Perform OS dependent initialisation. */
#ifdef WIN32
#else
#endif
    return result;
}

void lock_delete(lock* aLock)
{
    /* Perform OS dependent tidy tasks. */
#ifdef WIN32
#else
#endif
    free(aLock);
}

void lock_obtain(lock* aLock)
{
    /* OS dependent acquire. */
#ifdef WIN32
    KeAcquireSpinLock(&aLock->sem, &aLock->oldIrql);
#else
#endif
}

void lock_release(lock* aLock)
{
    /* OS dependent release. */
#ifdef WIN32
    KeReleaseSpinLock(&aLock->sem, aLock->oldIrql);
#else
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect the reason posted by hmjd. But, in my opinion, the solution can be as follows:

```
#define Get_Lock(lock)  { KIRQL  oldIrql;  KeAcquireSpinLock(&(lock),&oldIrql);  
#define Release_Lock(sync) KeReleaseSpinLock(&(sync),oldIrql) }
```

But, you need to ensure that Get_Lock & Release_Lock is in same scope which anyway you would be ensuring as per your comments.

The idea is mostly same as that of [pthread_cleanup_push & pthread_cleanup_pop](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cleanup_push). You can refer to the same also.